# Extract star rating details without code

Tags: 2013, rest, ootb, rating

I have enabled Star Rating for my list. Suppose 100 people have rated the list item,

How can I export which rating was given by which user? Need to export this data to excel without code through REST API.

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Without code, I'm not seeing a way to harvest the data.  You could try creating a SPD workflow, then write the input rating to another list.  (I haven't tested this)